# Transmit trades between Excel and R

Tags: r, excel, algorithmic-trading, blotter

Is there a way to make calls between R and Excel in order to run R quantstrat package using EOD data. Send proposed trades to an excel file (which has to be inserted manually as the broker does not have an API) and then import the trades from an excel file to R for continuous analysis? Thanks for your help

Comment: yes there is, what have you tried?

Comment: Use `openxlsx` library to write, `readxl` to read Excel files, Luke.

Comment: I have tried xlsx package functions write.xlsx and read.xlsx but I do not know what R function to use to extract the day's trades and what R function to use to insert the executed trades to blotter (?)

Comment: Should I use getOrders daily and addOrder for each trade? If I did this, could I avoid having to work through Excel?